# Hide / fold settings above an image

Tags: org-mode, code-folding

Is there way to "fold" settings, similar to how I can fold drawers? I have these properties associated with an image:

```
#+NAME: fig:figure name
#+CAPTION: figure name
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 200
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 2.0in
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 200
[[file:homepage.org_imgs/20210706_002617_ok9v4c.png]]
```

I'd like it to be foldable / unfoldable with TAB similar to a drawer. However, if I actually create a drawer, the properties no longer take effect because the :END: acts as a space before the image link.

For example this is foldable (like I want) but the settings no longer associate with the image:

```
:IMAGE_INFO:
#+NAME: fig:figure name
#+CAPTION: figure name
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 200
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 2.0in
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 200
:END:
[[file:homepage.org_imgs/20210706_002617_ok9v4c.png]]
```

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on lessons learned from John Kitchin's answer, this will "unpack" drawers both before rendering on the screen and exporting:

```
(defun unpack-image-drawers (&rest r)
  "Replace drawers named \"IMAGE_INFO\" with their contents."
  (let* ((drawer-name "IMAGE_INFO")
        (save-string "#+ATTR_SAVE: true\n")
        (image-drawers (reverse (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer)
                                'drawer
                              (lambda (el)
                                (when (string= drawer-name (org-element-property :drawer-name el))
                                  el))))))
    (cl-loop for drawer in image-drawers do
             (setf (buffer-substring (org-element-property :begin drawer)
                                     (- (org-element-property :end drawer) 1))
                   (concat save-string
                           (buffer-substring (org-element-property :contents-begin drawer)
                                             (- (org-element-property :contents-end drawer) 1)))))))

(defun repack-image-drawers (&rest r)
  "Restore image drawers replaced using `unpack-image-drawers'."
  (let* ((drawer-name "IMAGE_INFO")
        (save-string "#+ATTR_SAVE: true\n")
        (image-paragraphs (reverse (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer)
                               'paragraph
                             (lambda (el)
                               (when (string= "true" (nth 0 (org-element-property :attr_save el)))
                                 el))))))
    (cl-loop for paragraph in image-paragraphs do
             (setf (buffer-substring (org-element-property :begin paragraph)
                                     (- (org-element-property :contents-begin paragraph) 1))
                   (concat ":" drawer-name ":\n"
                           (buffer-substring (+ (length save-string) (org-element-property :begin paragraph))
                                             (- (org-element-property :contents-begin paragraph) 1))
                           "\n:END:")))))


(defun apply-with-image-drawers-unpacked (f &rest r)
  "Replace drawers named \"IMAGE_INFO\" with their contents, run the function,
finally restore the drawers as they were. Also collapses all drawers before returning."
  (unpack-image-drawers)
  (apply f r)
  (repack-image-drawers)
  (org-hide-drawer-all))

(advice-add #'org-display-inline-images :around #'apply-with-image-drawers-unpacked)
(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook 'unpack-image-drawers)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would stick with your image info drawers, and then use a preprocessing hook to remove the lines that cause a problem. Here is one example that just replaces the IMAGE_INFO drawers with their contents. You can collapse them in your org file, and export as usual when you use the hook at the end.

```
(defun preprocess-rm-image-info-drawers (_)
  (let ((img-drws (reverse (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer)
                   'drawer (lambda (drw)
                     (when
                         (string= "IMAGE_INFO" (org-element-property :drawer-name drw)) drw))))))
    (cl-loop for drw in img-drws do
         (setf (buffer-substring (org-element-property :begin drw) (org-element-property :end drw))
           (buffer-substring (org-element-property :contents-begin drw) (org-element-property :contents-end drw))))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook 'preprocess-rm-image-info-drawers)
```

Comment: I am also looking for the width of the image to be set in org-mode rendering itself (as a lot of the images are very large). The ATTR_ORG does this. So this solution helps with exporting, but doesn't address the visual clutter that I'm trying to get rid of while editing.

Comment: I wonder if I could add some sort of advice to org-display-inline-images to do something similar?

Comment: Maybe set org-image-actual-width to a reasonable default?

Comment: The problem with that is I have things ranging from full screenshots to icons that don't really make sense to have at a single size.

Comment: Leave the attr_org line between the drawer and figure?

Comment: That helps keep it down, but I wanted to eliminate it completely (save for the drawer header). Your answer taught me quite a bit however. I am new to emacs and lisp (about 2 weeks in). So I expanded upon what you did for a solution that works both for export and screen rendering.